# I get only 00000

Tags: c++, arrays

i want to create a new array that include negative numbers from array t. My code is running,ı have no error but I get only 00000

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t[3][12]={{-2,7,6,13},{48,-5,1,-7},{16,-9,2,-9}};
    int i,j,k;
    k=0;
    int a[12];
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++)
        {
            if(t[i][j]<0)
            {
                t[i][j]=a[k];
                k++;
                cout<<t[i][j];
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the content of array `a` ?

Comment: What do you think happens at the `t[i][j]=a[k];` statement?

Comment: Unrelated, but use `<iostream>`, not `"iostream"` for the standard headers.

Comment: Array `a` does not contain any initialized value. I guess your intention was to put the values to array `a'.

Comment: I don't see how the current duplicates have anything to do with this question. The problem is that OP have misunderstood how to do assignment. There are probably duplicates for that too though.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 4):

The error is in `t[i][j]=a[k]`, it should be `a[k] = t[i][j]`.

You are however not using `a` so the `cout<<t[i][j];` doesn't really give you any verification that you've filled `a` correctly.

You've also defined the inner array of `t` to have `12` elements, but you only explicitly initialize and use `4` of them. By changing `t` to `int t[3][4]` you can simplify the program by using [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and by printing out the initialized values in `a` *after* the outer loop you'd get a verification that you assigned the correct values to `a`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // You only use 4 elements in the inner array, not 12:
    int t[3][4] = {{-2, 7, 6, 13}, {48, -5, 1, -7}, {16, -9, 2, -9}};

    // This calculates the correct size of `a` even if you change the
    // number of elements in `t`:
    int a[sizeof t / sizeof(int)];
    
    unsigned k = 0;
    for(int(&inner)[4] : t) {    // a range-based for loop, easier written as
                                 // for(auto& inner : t)
        for(int value : inner) { // another range-based for loop
            if (value < 0) {
                a[k] = value;
                ++k;
            }
        }
    }

    // Verify that the values in a [0,k) are correct:
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i];
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```